# Keras + LSTM/RNN: trouble with dimensionality of `X`'s for new predictions

Tags: python, keras, lstm, dimensions, recurrent-neural-network

## Summary

I am having trouble being able to provide the proper dimensions for my **input data** into a **prediction** after the model has already been properly generated.

I'm receiving the following error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking : expected lstm_13_input to have shape (None, 40, 39) but got array with shape (1, 39, 39)
```

## Background

- Using Anaconda as my virtual environment
- Keras version 2.0.6
- TensorFlow version 1.1.0

I am creating an example fairly closely following [this tutorial](https://github.com/mineshmathew/char_rnn_karpathy_keras/blob/master/char_rnn_of_karpathy_keras.py).

## Code

And here are the relevant snippets of code:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Dropout
from keras.layers import LSTM,TimeDistributed,SimpleRNN
from keras.utils.data_utils import get_file
import numpy as np
from time import sleep
import random
import sys
```

...

```
X = np.zeros((len(sentences), maxlen, len(chars)), dtype=np.bool)
y = np.zeros((len(sentences),maxlen, len(chars)), dtype=np.bool) # y is also a sequence , or  a seq of 1 hot vectors
for i, sentence in enumerate(sentences):
    for t, char in enumerate(sentence):
        X[i, t, char_indices[char]] = 1

for i, sentence in enumerate(next_chars):
    for t, char in enumerate(sentence):
        y[i, t, char_indices[char]] = 1
```

...

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(512, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(maxlen, len(chars))))  # original one
model.add(LSTM(512, return_sequences=True)) #- original
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(len(chars))))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop')
```

...

```
history=model.fit(X, y, batch_size=128, nb_epoch=1,verbose=0)
```

...

```
seed_string="brutus:\nbeing so moved, he will not spare"
x=np.zeros((1, len(seed_string), len(chars)))
for t, char in enumerate(seed_string):
    x[0, t, char_indices[char]] = 1.
preds = model.predict(x, verbose=0)[0]
```

## Error

At this last line, it errors out, with the following error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking : expected lstm_13_input to have shape (None, 40, 39) but got array with shape (1, 39, 39)
```

## Efforts to Resolve

I have played with the **dimensionality of the `seed_string` and the `x` generated from it**, but no matter how I try to adjust them, I have some sort of mis-match, always due to this requirement of `None` (I think).  To be clear, I had either added or taken away characters from the seed string, so that it is `40` characters. However, when I set it to `40`, the error says I actually have `41`, and when I set it to `39`, it says I have `39`, as shown above.  There is something else - which I don't understand - going on here.

I looked at [`Reshape`'s code](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/core.py#L294) and an [example of how to use it](https://keras.io/layers/core/), but since Keras' `Reshape` is meant for ***model layers***, I don't even understand how I could use it to reshape the input to the prediction, and Numpy has no way to reshape creating a `None` dimension (at least not to my knowledge).

Answer (score 1):

The length of your `seed_string` needs to match `maxlen`. You can handle both the scenario of your string being shorter or longer than `maxlen` with [`pad_sequences`](https://keras.io/preprocessing/sequence/#pad_sequences). In your case your string is too long.

```
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

seed_string = "brutus:\nbeing so moved, he will not spare"

x = np.zeros((1, len(seed_string), len(chars)))

for t, char in enumerate(seed_string):
    x[0, t, char_indices[char]] = 1.

x = pad_sequences(x, maxlen=maxlen)

preds = model.predict(x, verbose=0)[0]
```

Comment: Hi @Nicole thanks for the suggestion, but as I'd said in the original question, I already did this.  To be clear, I *see* that the `40` & `39` do not match in the sizes `(None, 40, 39)` and `(1, 39, 39)`.  But the size of the seed string is not the issue, even though it seems it is.  (In fact, it will say that it's either 39, or jump up to 41, even when I add only 1 character).  The issue seems to be something else, which I cannot quite tell.

Comment: Did you actually try using pad_sequences or did you just try changing the length of the string?

Comment: I just changed the length.  I did not know about [pad_sequence](https://keras.io/preprocessing/sequence/#pad_sequences).  I'll try that.  However, I did already have them as `numpy` arrays with the proper number of dimensions.  (E.g., I shortened the length of the string, ***then*** vectorized the string into a one-hot encoded `numpy` multi-dimensional array with the proper # of dimensions.)

Comment: I ask because it seems most likely to me there's a bug in your code and you are passing in the wrong shape for `x`. The only way I can reproduce your error is to make `x` the wrong dimension. If you could paste a full reproduction of what you're doing to ensure the string is the right length, that would be helpful. Try printing `x.shape` right before passing it to `predict`. Also try using `pad_sequences`, as it would ensure you have the correct timestep dimension regardless of what you've done in attempts to manipulate its dimensions elsewhere.